# Using `runhaskell` with command-line arguments

Tags: shell, haskell, command-line-arguments

I have a file named `"test.txt"` with this text:

```
Good
Morning
Sir
```

and a file named `"test.hs"` with the following code:

```
module Main where

import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = interact f

f :: String -> String
f s = head $ lines s
```

The following command...

`cat test.txt | runhaskell test.hs`

outputs

`Good`

---

However, I would like to explicitly pass parameters to `runhaskell` without relying on a file, like:

`echo "Good\nMorning\nSir" | runhaskell test.hs`

and also execute `runhaskell` with a literal string of Haskell code, like:

`echo "Good\nMorning\nSir" | runhaskell "module Main where\nimport System.IO\nmain :: IO ()\nmain = interact f\nf :: String -> String\nf s = head $ lines s"`

Is this technically possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that echo will output a backslash (`\`) and an `n` instead of a new line.

You can use the [**`-e`** flag [unix.com]](https://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/1/echo/), this flag will:

> `-e` enable interpretation of backslash escapes

So we can pass a string with new lines to `runhaskell`'s input channel with:

```
echo -e -- "Good\nMorning\nSir" | runhaskell test.hs
```

Note that `cat test.txt | runhaskell test.hs` is [*useless use of `cat`*](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html), you can replace this with:

```
runhaskell test.hs < test.txt
```

which is more efficient since we do not use a `cat` process or the pipe to pass data to.

Comment: Thank you so much. Why do you have two dashes after `-e` ?

Comment: @F.Zer: that is to prevent that the content of the string, is interpreted as a flag. Here that is not the case, but imagine that the string for example is `-n`, then `echo` parses this as a flag. By using two dashes, it is seen as a parameter: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean

Comment: Thank you ! Do you know whether my second concern is technically possible ?